# How to use setState for an imported RN piece

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I cannot change the state of an imported RN piece.

I try:

```
this.setState({myState: "This does not do anything"})
```

But it does not work. I am suspecting the problem is this - referring the main document only. But I don't know how to change it.

Interestingly,

```
state = {myState: 'Now it is changed'}
this.setState({})
```

this works. But from what I have read here it is not recommended.

Thank you!

```
// MAIN FILE

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { TestImport } from './TestImport';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  _onPressChange = () => {
  state = {myState: 'Now it is changed'}
  this.setState({})
  // the above commented piece works - strangely enough

  this.setState({myState: "This does not do anything"})
  // this does not work 

}

  constructor (props) {
 super(props)
this.state = {
    myState: 'to this'
}
}

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
     <View>
     <TestImport></TestImport>    
     </View>
    <View>
    <Button title="Click to change" onPress={() => this._onPressChange()}/>
    </View>
    </View>

    );
}
}


// IMPORTED FILE
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

this.state = {
    myState: 'Change this'
}

const TestImport = (props) => {

   return (
        <View>
        <Text>{this.state.myState} </Text>
    </View>

     )
}

export { TestImport };
```

Comment: `this.setState({})` will change your state to empty object I think.

Comment: add some info what are you trying to achieve apart from setState, because you have used a state as a normal variable not a class state in TestImport file.

Comment: Ultimately I want to build reusable UI pieces which states I want to control from the main file. I am new to RN and don't know the difference between normal variable and class state.

Answer (score 0):

Flow is not like that. Your `TestImport` i.e imported component should read it from the props.

```
// IMPORTED FILE
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const TestImport = (props) => {

   return (
       <View>
            <Text>{props.title} </Text>
       </View>
   )
}

export { TestImport };
```

And pass it from your main component

```
<TestImport title={this.state.myState}></TestImport>
```

So when you click on button, it will rerender whole component which includes your `TestImport` also and will pass latest state value of `myState` through prop name `title`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to change the state of the imported file afterwards. So I need to change the state and not props.

Comment: If you are changing state imported file and it should be reflected in parent component than you have to manage it either in redux or you can pass that value to parent and keep it in some variable

Answer (score 0):

> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>   import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
>   import TestImport from './TestImport';

export default class App extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        myState: 'to this'
    }
}
_onPressChange = () => {
    this.setState({ myState: 'hello everyone do this' })

}


render() {
    //   console.log(this.state,'love')
    return (
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <View>
                <TestImport name={this.state.myState} />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Button title="Click to change" onPress={() => this._onPressChange()} />
            </View>
        </View>

    );
}
```

}

//app.js

> import React from 'react';
>   import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

this.state = {
    myState: 'Change this'
}

const TestImport = (props) => {
    console.log(props.name, 'props')
    return (
        
            {props.name}

```
)
```

}

export default TestImport;
  // importtest.js

Answer (score 0):

If you have a use case, that you need to use `state` instead of `props` like [@Ravi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644587/2963461), you can do it this way (disclaimer: you still need props :D)

```js
class TestImport extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myState: 'Change this'
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {changedState} = this.props;
    if(changedState && changedState !== prevProps.changedState)
      this.setState({myState: changedState})
  }
  ...
}
```

and on your parent,

```js
<TestImport changedState={this.state.myState} />
```

You always need to use `props` to 'communicate' between components. Either `props` or a state management library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html)